# matplotlib inline plots all figures after all text

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

In jupyter notebook, with `%matplotlib inline` enabled, the output of a cell that both prints text and plots a figure will have the entirety of the text appear before the figure is shown.  This happens even if the figure was generated (and called show() on) before the text was printed.

For example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.show()
print "hello"
```

will show the 'hello' before the empty figure.

How do I fix this so that each figure appears truly inline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to explicitly `display` the figure, using IPython's display function:

```
from IPython.display import display

fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111)
display(fig)
print("hello")
```

Comment: That worked, with the added caveat that you have to add `plt.close()` at the end to make it not print the figure a second time.  Thanks!